# When I receive image path from database using ajax in codeigniter. it gives me error in the image path

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I receive image path from database using ajax in codeigniter. it gives me that error. This is the function from which the image is received from database.

```
public function master_get_employees()
    {
        if ($this->input->post()) { //If Any Values Posted
            if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) { //If Request Generated From Ajax
                $ID = $this->input->post('ID');
                if (!isset($ID) || !is_numeric($ID)) {
                    echo "FAIL::Something went wrong with POST request, Please contact system administrator for further assistance::error";
                    return;
                }
                $table = "employees e";
                $selectData = "e.id AS ID,e.Picture as pic,e.IsEnabled";
                $where = array(
                    'e.id' => $ID, 'e.IsActive' => 1
                );
                $result = $this->Common_model->select_fields_where_like_join($table, $selectData, $where, TRUE);
                print json_encode($result);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the error is that.
[image: this is the error]

Comment: That is not an “error”, but the standard escaping of the `/` character that gets applied when you use json_encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the "json_encode" is added that forward slashes to the path you can replace this code

```
  print json_encode($result);
```

With This code

```
print json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 3):

May it is stored wrong in db I mean you use **"/"** instead of **"\"**
change it and see if it appears

or write a code on your frontend which replace "/" with "\" in coming image url .

Comment: this is in the databse "assets/employee_profile/6e3678f5646a1838e7ac40bead.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

PHP's json_encode, by default, escapes slashes.

You can override this by doing

```
json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```